# grails generated controller test fails after moving from Grails 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: grails

When I generate a controller and the associated unit test class using grails 2.4.4, I'm getting test failures even after I setup the necessary test data in populateValidParams(). I can fix most several of the failures by just changing the **model.personInstance != null** (for a Person class) to **model.person != null**. I'm surprised that this is necessary, but at least it is working.

The other test failures are on the *save*, *update* and *delete* related tests and fails because **response.redirectUrl** is null. From stepping through it with the debugger, it appears that the **request.withFormat** closure is hitting the wildcard statement rather than the **form/multipartForm** block. I thought that the **request.contentType = FORM_CONTENT_TYPE** in the generated unit test should have caused the code to hit the **form/multipartForm** part of the code.

Here's the code that that I am testing with for a Person domain class that requires only the firstName and lastName fields...

**Domain Class:**

```
package org.crspta.gohomenotes
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode()
class Person implements Serializable {

User user

Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated

String firstName
String middleName
String lastName
String nickname
String emailAddress
String cellPhone
String homePhone
String workPhone

static constraints = {
    firstName nullable: false
    middleName nullable: true
    lastName nullable: false
    nickname nullable: true
    emailAddress nullable: true, email: true
    cellPhone nullable: true
    homePhone nullable: true
    workPhone nullable: true
    user nullable: true
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "${name}"
}  

public String getName() {
    def name = "$lastName, $firstName"
    if (nickname) {
        name += " ($nickname)"
    }
    return name
}
}
```

**PersonControllerSpec:**

```
@TestFor(PersonController)
@Mock(Person)
class PersonControllerSpec extends Specification {

def populateValidParams(params) {
    assert params != null
    params["firstName"] = 'Firstname'
    params["lastName"] = 'Lastname'
}
```

*Unit Test Method that is Failing because response.redirectUrl is null.*

```
    void "Test the save action correctly persists an instance"() {

    when:"The save action is executed with an invalid instance"
        request.contentType = FORM_CONTENT_TYPE
        request.method = 'POST'
        def person = new Person()
        person.validate()
        controller.save(person)

    then:"The create view is rendered again with the correct model"
        model.person != null
        view == 'create'

    when:"The save action is executed with a valid instance"
        response.reset()
        populateValidParams(params)
        person = new Person(params)

        controller.save(person)

    then:"A redirect is issued to the show action"
        response.redirectedUrl == '/person/show/1'
        controller.flash.message != null
        Person.count() == 1
}
```

**PersonController save() method:**

```
    @Transactional
def save(Person personInstance) {
    if (personInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (personInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond personInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    personInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), personInstance.id])
            redirect personInstance
        }
        '*' { respond personInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

**Specific Error Message:**

```
Condition not satisfied:

response.redirectedUrl == '/person/show/1'
|        |             |
|        null          false
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletResponse@17134f55
 <Click to see difference>

at org.crspta.gohomenotes.PersonControllerSpec.Test the save action correctly persists an instance(PersonControllerSpec.groovy:56)
```